Scipy, PyInstaller: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arpack: The specified module could not be found.,
Using PyInstaller to created exefile, *.bat:
@echo off
cd /d  "python_path"

    python -m PyInstaller --collect-submodules MyClass.py ^
        --collect-submodules __init__.py ^
        --collect-all  scipy ^
        --hidden-import=scipy.optimize ^
        --hidden-import=scipy.iterative ^ # Returns that does not exist. 
        --additional-hooks-dir=.hook-scipy.py ^
        --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data "path"/customtkinter;customtkinter/ "file_path".py 
    
    pause

File hook-scipy.py :
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

hiddenimports = collect_submodules('scipy')

datas = collect_data_files('scipy')

In the code importing scipy as :
from scipy import optimize

However I do still received the error when trying to run the exe file :
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "scipy\sparse\linalg\_eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 48, in <module>
    from . import _arpack
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arpack: The specified module could not be found.


Also if I check the executable file folder I can see that there is certain scipy module is the file structure. It seems it is just not recognized or so. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks
